# Is there a way to change Windows crasy long line Alpha sort?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I do not know if it is possible but this drives me up the wall.

A) When trying to view my disks/partitions (more than 16) using explorer in "computer" and it has the cool new Disk Used/Free bars, but the column sort order is reading left to right, instead of columns.

A picture would be better, but here is an ASKII pic. When set for View TILES mode, it looks like this, where you read the next one from left to right.

```
Disk A [=====-----]  Disk B [=====-----]  Disk C [=====-----]
Disk D [======----]  Disk E [=====-----]  Disk F [=====-----]
Disk G [=====-----]  Disk H [======----]  Disk I [=====-----] 
Disk J [=====-----]  Disk K [======----]  Disk L [======----] 
Disk M [====------]  Disk N [====------]  Disk O [====------]  
Disk P [======----]
```

Quick try and find the space used on the F disk.

Doesn't it make much more sence, and allow a person to View and Scan and Find something alphabetically if it would sort like this?

```
Disk A [=====-----]  Disk G [=====-----]  Disk L [=====-----]
Disk B [======----]  Disk H [=====-----]  Disk M [=====-----]
Disk C [=====-----]  Disk I [======----]  Disk N [=====-----] 
Disk D [=====-----]  Disk J [======----]  Disk O [======----] 
Disk E [====------]  Disk K [====------]  Disk P [====------]  
Disk F [======----]
```

If you were laying out columns in Word, Excell, a Newspaper, or even in a book, or anywhere else other than a MS computer, wouldn't the above be the method used?

When set to View CONTENT, sorting is correct, I can still get the cool Freespace icon, but then it wastes space, Without seeing them ALL in a nice sized window. The sort is correct, but the space is poorly utalised.

```
Disk A [=======================------------------------] 
Disk B [=======================------------------------]
Disk C [=======================------------------------]
Disk D [=======================------------------------]
Disk E [=======================------------------------]
Disk F [=======================------------------------]
Disk G [=======================------------------------]
Disk H [=======================------------------------]
Disk I [=======================------------------------]
Disk J [=======================------------------------]
Disk K [=======================------------------------]
Disk L [=======================------------------------]
---About here I have to start scrolling,
and there are often removable disks to go also---
```

---

B) The same bad sorting is in my Control Pannel. HOW do people find anything in there when it is set to small icons or large Icons?  Open up the control pannel, and switch to the small icon or large icon view, and Alphabetically find the power options. The control pannel cannot be set to a "details" type of view with a straight column, unless you resize the window, forcing it to one column.

```
A       A     B      B      C       C
D       D     E      E      F       F
G       H     I      J      K       L
```

If your thinking "It's you man, your brain doesnt work" and the above looks perfectally normal to you, then dont try and answer the question.   If you understand what I am saying, then please tell me how to rearange this mess on Windows 7.

It really adds to the insanity, when some of the usual explorer file sorting is "normal" for columns. EX: Open up a folder with hundreds of items , and switch to LIST View , then try other views. With the normal file exploring, I am usually in Details mode, so the crasyness there never bothered me.

Comment: On the other hand, when you look through a picture gallery, you read from left to right, not Top to bottom.  And when you use a Flow Layout Control, it does the same thing.  Heck, Program Manager in Windows 3.1, Flickr, Google images, even Stack Exchange use the left to right for gravatars.

Comment: When searching based ON a Graphic pic or a thumbnail, it doesnt bother me, this only gets me when I am trying to find based on the alphabetical stuff I got programmed into me in 1st grade :-) Luckily that great method of typing the first one (or few) letters of something solves most of the "find the file in the thousands".  In control pannel I might not know the exact Name, something that took 1/2 a second with toolbars (custom layout) now takes longer to find than to adjust.

Comment: +1. This also bothers me. I see that `dir` has a switch to give the better ordering: `"/d : Same as /w but files are sorted by column".` And, interestingly, Unix `ls` has the *reverse* switch `"-x list entries by lines instead of by columns".`